# Hot Module Replacement(HMR) not working on angular(8/9/10)

Tags: angular8, angular9, angular10, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I tried implementing HMR with angular version 8/9/10. But changing code reloads the complete page every time.
I used following link to make the exact changes:
https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/enabling-hot-module-replacement-angular-6/

Am I missing something?